# Specify what database to use when adding relation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I know I can specify a database to use with "using" keyword like this:

```
zoo = Zoo.objects.using(db_id).get(pk=123)
```

But how can I specify database to use when I am adding a relation?

```
animal = Animal(name="Lion")
zoo.animals.add(animal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `Zoo` and `Animal` model which you `get` by specifying the database. Relations cannot exist across different databases. So the `ManyToMany` add implictly implies that `Add the relation to the same database as the Zoo and Animal instances which need to belong to the same database`